# Execute SQL script to create tables and rows

Tags: mysql, terminal

I have a database that I created using the CREATE DATABASE statement in the terminal and I have a .sql file full of statements creating tables and rows.

I just wanted to know what was the command line to execute that .sql on the database I created?

Comment: That would depend on which database you're using; every one has a different command line command. Edit your question to include the DB type and I imagine you'll get a more useful answer :-)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

In the MySQL interactive client you can type:

```
source yourfile.sql
```

Alternatively you can pipe the data into mysql from the command line:

```
mysql < yourfile.sql
```

If the file doesn't specify a database then you will also need to add that:

```
mysql db_name < yourfile.sql
```

See the documentation for more details:

- [Executing SQL Statements from a Text File](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html)

Comment: Amazing! This worked for me:

`source /home/kholofelo/Desktop/mydb.sql`

this worked after logging into my mysql and dropped to the commandline

Comment: Worth mentioning that quotes are not needed around filepath. Otherwise it returns 'Failed to open file ... error 2'. Go without quotes.

Answer (score 20):

If you have password for your dB then

```
mysql -u <username> -p <DBName> < yourfile.sql
```