# Importing Excel CSV to MySQL relational database?

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I have two tables `baskets` and `fruits`; a `basket` has many different `fruits` so it's a one to many relation.

The tables are as follows:

```
baskets 
id NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
basket_name varchar(20)

fruits 
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
fruit_name varchar(20),
basket_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES baskets(id)
```

I have an Excel sheet with column names and data organized like this:

```
Basket Fruits 

Basket_1 Apple, Mango, Banana, Pear

Basket_2 Mango, Strawberry, Plums, Banana, Grapes

Baskt_3 Raspberry, Apple, Pear
```

What would be the best possible way to store all these fruits for a single basket in the relational architecture modeled above?

I have converted my XLS file to CSV for better parsing using scripts (in Ruby) and found that the table has been messed up such that each fruit is now in a separate cell and the number of cells vary for one basket (in a row) in the spreadsheet.

My question is some what similar to this: [Import Excel Data to Relational Tables at MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933544/import-excel-data-to-relational-tables-at-mysql)

But not the same in data.

All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Did you already create some models? Please show us the work you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of problems always seem to take a fair amount of steps.

If the fruits are in separate cells, use the paste - transpose tool in Excel to turn rows into columns by copying all cells in one sheet and then using paste special - transpose to paste them in a new sheet.

In a third sheet i would make a formula that concatenates the value of each cell, starting in the second row, with the value in the first row. If sheetA has the freshly transposed values, and sheetB is the new sheet, the formula would be `=sheetA!a$1 & "," & sheetA!a2`, and copy that formula from a2:zz999 or however far it needs to go.

Then the columns need to be concatenated, which can be done manually, or via UNION statements in Mysql after the sheet is imported:

```
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM SHEETB
UNION
SELECT COLUMN2 FROM SHEETB
UNION
...
```

You get the idea. Once the combined basket-fruit field is in one column, it's easy to separate out into two columns.